# Sudo option is missing

Tags: polkadot-js, rococo, sudo

I just clone the Polkadot repo v0.9.20 and build. When I run the chain sudo option is not showing in developer section.
Running chain on 127.0.0.1:9944.
Can anyone please tell why this thing happen?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

When the pallet doesn't show, it means it is not included in the runtime.

Since the Polkadot repo is meant to support the live/production Polkadot network, this module is not included in the [runtime config](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/016dc7297101710db0483ab6ef199e244dff711d/runtime/polkadot/src/lib.rs#L1391-L1484). Polkadot is deployed with democracy to take care of all root operations.

This is unlike Substrate itself which is a sample node and therefore does have [sudo in the runtime](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/bc310fdd1040af8a3d2901b5d6f4cf8d5250aeb7/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1600).

Answer (score 2):

git cherrypick this commit and read the commit comment for the step to fixup the Cargo.toml after:
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/commit/791c8b8f9e6fe00b631f2cace0d6d65151487eb4

That will quickly add sudo to polkadot (for testing purposes).