# I can't open a HRMP channel between the parachains

Tags: polkadot-js, parachain, xcm, xcmp

I am testing XCM between parachain 2000 and parachain 2001 while referencing this link, [How to open HRMP channels between parachains?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5445/how-to-open-hrmp-channels-between-parachains).
But I couldn't open a new HRMP channel, I faced the "Barrier" error.

It seems I should use Sudo or Governance as you said, but I could find neither of them in the "Developer" tag on the Polkadot.JS App.

So I added Sudo option as referencing the link - https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/commit/791c8b8f9e6fe00b631f2cace0d6d65151487eb4.
But after clicking the "Extrinsics->Sudo->sudo(call)" button, the Polkadot-js App crashed.

[image]

What am I missing now?

Comment: As others have noted, you will have to either include the sudo pallet or governance pallets. Additionally, make sure you are using the parachain's sovereign account.

Comment: Thanks, @Bruno, I am fixing the issues now as all you mentioned.

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

> Since this tutorial is for example purposes, both parachains should
> have the sudo pallet configured. In a production chain this would be
> substituted with governance.

If you followed the [Zombienet](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4692/how-do-i-spin-up-a-testnet-with-zombienet) tutorial to launch the parachains, make sure your chain has the sudo pallet and create the binaries again.

Answer (score 0):

The sudo tab will show up only when you have the sudo key in your wallet.

The governance tab will show up only when the runtime have pallet-democracy.

Answer (score 0):

First, check if your runtime has a sudo pallet(like [this line](https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia-parachain/blob/main/runtime/crab-parachain/src/lib.rs#L170)), if not, refer to this answer https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/3203/1959 to introduce it.

And then, as xavier said, make sure the sudo key(like [this line](https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia-parachain/blob/main/src/chain_spec/crab_parachain.rs#L121)) in your wallet.