# Sudo option is not showing up on PolkadotUI - Substrate

Tags: polkadot-js, sudo

I am running a substrate-permissioned network,  we configure the SUDO account using the keys on polkadot UI account and use it to perform node authorization, etc.

Since last week, SUDO option is not showing up Polkadot UI. We are following the same steps and we haven't made changes to the code.

FYI, SUDO pallet was configured from begin.

Please through some light on this[image]

Comment: This has already been answered here https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3200/sudo-option-is-missing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sudo option is missing](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3200/sudo-option-is-missing)

Comment: Nope. These are two different situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only when the PolkadotApps detect the sudo key in your wallet, the sudo component will be loaded.

---

After some discussions.

I found the Substrate version is quite old. If you open your browser console, you will see a lot of errors. Your node be incompatible with the latest PolkadotApps. I guess this is the reason why the sudo pallet fails to load.

Comment: We have added the SUDO keys, and as I mentioned we have been using the SUDO key for more than a year. But now PolkadotApps doesn't show the sudo option even if I add the sudo keys.

Comment: What's your Substrate version? Could you share the testnet link?

Comment: We use older version v2.0.0, link: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fatom2.api.godscilla.com%2Frpc#/accounts

Comment: That's quite old. If you open your browser console, you will see a lot of errors. You might be incompatible with the latest PolkadotApps. I guess this is the reason why the sudo pallet fail to load.

Comment: Sorry. *Your node might be

Comment: Thanks for the response, Is there a way I can use the old version of PolkadotApps?..Because we are running prod private network with the old version. Definitely we will consider upgrading the newer version. For the time being, is there any workaround to use polkadot older version?

Comment: I think the only way is git clone polkadot-apps & checkout old version tag & yarn. If anyone knows other ways. Please correct me.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The issue is resolved, I have cloned the older version and run it. Appreciate your timely help

Comment: Could you mark this as the answer?

Comment: This has already been answered here https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3200/sudo-option-is-missing